# css background fixed fails after resizing window

Tags: css, background, background-image, fixed, css-position

I have spent few hours of trying to make background fixed and in the center. I hope you could show where I made silly mistakes.

My code

```
#main_inside{
        float:right;
        margin-top:223px;
        width:700px;    
        background:url("images/gidas.png") no-repeat fixed 496px 259px transparent;
        margin-bottom: 86px;
    }
```

The problem is when I re-size window with crtl + scroll. The image gets away.

I have also tried:

```
background-position:center;
```

and tried this:

```
background-origin:content-box;
```

and tried using % to set image distance.

Real problem URL http://lyderiai.net/tg2013/gidas.php

Answer (score 0):

When you use "fixed" you are making the image fixed to the viewport of the website (a.k.a the window), so for example if you set it to "background-position: left 0" it won't take the div left postion, but the window left position. 
So that's why when you resize your window, the image will move.

Comment: I have tried background-position: left 0, but no luck. Is the easy or complicated way to make picture laying in the center for all window sizes?

Comment: I gave an example, that it won't work the way you are doing it. A simple way is to add the background to the body tag. (or some div that takes 100% of the width of the window)

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong with that design, but even when I add to body it doesn't work